# Unresolved external symbol for AcquireCredentialsHandleW

Tags: c++

I have a cpp file that has these includes:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <sspi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <credssp.h>
```

When trying to run AcquireCredentialsHandleW I get..

```
unresolved external symbol __imp_AcquireCredentialsHandleW referenced in function main
```

MSDN says it is in sspi.h.

Comment: You are confusing the declaration (found in sspi.h) and the implementaion found in Secur32.lib.  You need to link with the library to fix the `unresolved external symbol` error.  See the __Requirements__ section here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/acquirecredentialshandle--general

Answer (score 0):

Go in the properties dialog of your project. You need to add the Secur32.lib files in the property below:
Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies.